# how to bind a textbox value from User Control to another Window in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a User control. There i have a textbox. If i set any value in the textbox, then i click "Select" button in the User control. what i want is, in my window page, i have another textbox. I want to Bind the Text value which is already selected in the User control textbox. I have the following code.
User control:

```
   <UserControl x:Class="Usercontrol1" x:Name="root">
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               x:Name="txtAuto" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
            <Button Name="btn_setectedType" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Select"  Click="btn_setectedType_Click"/>                

   </Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

this is my Window page..

```
  <Window x:Class="Window1" Title="Facility" >

      <Grid>
         <TextBox x:Name="txtUserSelection" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Text="{Binding ???}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
      </Grid>
 </Window>
```

I don't know how to continue further. i tried to create Object for this Window and tried to pass directly from User Control. but it fails. My requirement is, whenever i change the value in Usercontrol, the value should bind on the Textbox in Window. Could anyone please help?

Comment: I feel that you need to go off and learn WPF better, before you come back here to ask questions... the problem is that you don't seem to know enough to even understand the answers that you have been provided with and this is not a website where you can come to learn a language... that's *your* job.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a ViewModel that holds the property you want to share between controls, and set that as the DataContext for both your MainWindow and your UserControl. Then you should bind both these TextBoxes to that property.

An example ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string MyProperty {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set { _myProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");}
    }
}
```

And using it in XAML:

```
<Window [...]>
    <Window.DataContext>
         <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
    <UserControl1 />
```

Here, your UserControl1 will already have its DataContext set to the same as the Window, and you can just mirror the Binding from the TextBox. You don't specify where your UserControl is created, so I can't be more specific than this.

Comment: I am new to wpf. Could you share any link for this? or could you provide some example for this?

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you still need elaborations, please don't hesitate to ask. But I am missing a key ingredient in provided a working answer: Where do you use your UserControl1?

Comment: To be frank i don't really understand where can i use that view model. i am using my User control in same Application only.

Comment: You can use that ViewModel anywhere it is the DataContext. In my example, that means anywhere within your Window. '{Binding MyProperty}' means 'show me the value of the MyProperty property on the object that is set as the DataContext'. I would strongly advise reading up on Bindings in WPF if you do not know what a DataContext is.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `string` property to your `MainWindow` code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StringValueProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("StringValue", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata("Some default value"));

public string StringValue
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(StringValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StringValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Then you can data bind from your `UserControl` directly to this property in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUserSelection" Text="{Binding StringValue, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: what is the code in User control? there i have a select button. after click that button only, my Text value from User control will bind in my Main window